How to get my localhost application to run with UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps Script
I'm trying to create an add-on for my application on Google Sheet. My application is still in development on localhost. I forwarded the url localhost:3001 with ngrok and get the application running in Apps Scripts but the index.html is not routing to assets.
Any help would be appreciated.
this is the code
function getData() {
  const url = "••••••"; 
  const options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "true",

    },

  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);   
  return response.getContentText();
}

function doGet(){
  const html = getData();
  Logger.log(html);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

}

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="basic gpx/tcx data analysis app" />
    <title>mycorr</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-CYckigfU.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/react-DNzqxdh-.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/mui-CYjvO3ta.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/react-CM9Skd9z.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-CP7RGrzZ.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>


Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example with your expected output.

index.html is not routing to assets. Was there an error? If so, please quote it.

I'm using Vite and React for frontend that's why there is no public url in index.html. The web application works fine but when trying to get it in apps script, its just empty page without any errors

This is because the url is hosted on Google's servers and has an unique url.
href="/assets/react-CM9Skd9z.css"

is interpreted as
href="https://[id]-script.googleusercontent.com/assets/react-CM9Skd9z.css"

And no such file is available on the servers. Consider using a bundler like es-build to bundle it all into one file and serve it through ngrok  through UrlFetchApp.
